# Entity Framework any way to return SQL as a result of IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-6.1

Assuming EF6.1 is in use....

Assuming that 'Category' is a POCO type that EF persists, that 'context' has a DbSet property called 'categories', that 'x' is defined as a legitimate local of type int, and that c.ID is also of type int.....

Given the following expression

```
context.Categories.Where<Category>((Category c) => {return c.ID == x});
```

Is there a way, before the query happens, to return the compiled SQL statement as a string without hitting the Database?

Comment: Call ToString? Have you tried?

Comment: Thanks! I seem to remember reading somewhere else about that a while back but I totally forgot. It's back in my memory now. I would definitely describe this as one of those EF 'gotchas'...it'd be nice if there was a more explict method name like ToSQLString()

Answer (score 1):

```
public IQueryable<Category> GetCategory(int x)
{
   return context.Categories.Where<Category>(c => c.ID == x);
}
```

To see SQL:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetCategory(1).ToString());
```